# When will automorphism group that fixes group element contain only identity element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

$\newcommand{\Aut}{\mathrm{Aut}}$Let $C_{\Aut(G)}(x)=\{\alpha \in \Aut(G) \mid \alpha(x)=x\}$, where $\Aut(G)$ is automorphism group of $G$.

> So, my question is for a non-abelian group is there exist any $x$ such that $C_{\Aut(G)}(x)= \{I\}$ or there does not exist any $x$ such that $C_{\Aut(G)}(x)= \{I\}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1.** $x$ centralises itself.

**Hint 2.** if $x\not\in Z(G)$ then there exists a map from $C_G(x)$ to $C_{\operatorname{Aut}(G)}(x)$ whose image is non-trivial (why?).

Comment: Please elaborate the concept  you are trying to explain. Can u give  any example of non abelian group where there exist any x such that $C_{Aut(G)}(x)={I}$.  Thankyou

Comment: No. If you edit your question to add more context or other details then I will elaborate. That is: say what you have tried and where you got stuck.